# changes to state issued from custom hook not causing re-render even though added to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that keeps a list of toggle states and while I'm seeing the internal state aligning with my expectations, I'm wondering why a component that listens to changes on the state kept by this hook isn't re-rendering on change.  The code is as follows

```
const useToggle = () => {
  const reducer = (state, action) => ({...state, ...action});
  const [toggled, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});
  const setToggle = i => {
    let newVal;
    if (toggled[i] == null) {
      newVal = true;
    } else {
      newVal = !toggled[i];
    }
    dispatch({...toggled, [i]: newVal});
    console.log('updated toggled state ...', toggled);
  };
  return {toggled, setToggle};
};

const Boxes = () => {
  const {setToggle} = useToggle()
  return Array.from({length: 8}, el => null).map((el,i) => 
  <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => setToggle(i)}/>)
  }

function App() {
  const {toggled} = useToggle()
  const memoized = useMemo(() => toggled, [toggled])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('toggled state is >>>', toggled) // am not seeing this on console after changes to toggled
  }, [toggled])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Boxes />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because you are using `useToggle` twice.

1. once in the `App`
2. another one in the `Boxes`.

When you dispatch the action in `Boxes`, it's updating the `toggled` instance for `Boxes` (which is not retrieved in it).

Think of your custom hook like how you use `useState`. When you use `useState`, each component gets its own state. Same goes for the custom hook.

So there are a few ways you can address the issue.

1. Pass the `setToggle` from `App` to `Boxes` via prop-drilling
2. Use Context API (or Redux or other statement management library to pass
   `setToggle` instance in the `App` component down)

Here is an example of prop-drilling.
*You can follow along*
[image: Edit so.answer.57130413]

```
const Boxes = ({ setToggle }) => {
  // const { setToggle } = useToggle();
  return Array.from({ length: 8 }, el => null).map((el, i) => (
    <input key={i} type="checkbox" onClick={() => setToggle(i)} />
  ));
};

function App() {
  const { toggled, setToggle } = useToggle();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("toggled state is >>>", toggled); // am not seeing this on console after changes to toggled
  }, [toggled]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Boxes setToggle={setToggle} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Note: that I added `key` props in `Boxes` using the index `i`(and it is a bad practice by the way)*

You can see that it's now working as you'd expect.
[image: demo]

Comment: From what I understand, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html shows that a custom hook is a way to avoid props drilling through calling the custom hook in the component you want to share state with and that was how I intended to build this particular hook.  Otherwise, I could have simply set state directly in App and pass the setter into Boxes without the use of a custom hook.

Comment: You can use hooks to "share logics", not states. You can search for `Do two components using the same Hook share state? No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic` in the documentation. It's tricky to understand and I still do after so long 

Comment: I recently started using [Zustand](https://github.com/react-spring/zustand), which works the way you intended. You create a hook, and states are shared! Very nice (& [small](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=zustand@2.2.3), 650b gzipped!) library.